# How can you tell what version of minecraft you have?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can you tell what version of Minecraft you have? I have tried looking in the app store and it doesn't show me the version I have.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a bit more information.

I'm assuming you play on IOS, since you mentioned App Store. On IOS, one can simply check the latest by searching up the app name and clicking on it. Bellow, it should say something like, (What's new in Version X: ...) And X will tell you the latest version.

EDIT: If it doesn't show, scroll all the way down, and somewhere, it should either tell you the latest version, or your current. (I'm not sure here, someone correct me)

If your looking to update your game, in the updates tab, you will find info on the newest version, it's size in KB, MB or GB, and much more.

If you would like to see your current version, simply launch Minecraft, and on the main menu, bellow, it indicates what version it has.(I have had minecraft before on IOS, then I decided to reset my device)